# when checkbox is disable then it should not be deleted

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This is the code to check all check box

```
$('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
```

But I need like when checkbox is disable then it should not be checked in multiple checkbox

So what will be the condition.

Comment: `$(':checkbox:not(:disabled)').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);` https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/

Comment: thanks its working ..

Comment: $('.classname').not(this).not(':disabled').prop('checked', this.checked);
this one is working .. thank you

Comment: @poojanmehtaPM this should not be tagged with `angularjs`, otherwise you have a completely wrong approach, as jQuery should not be used at all

Comment: but you can use jquery function in angularjs as well and i just make multiple checkbox select with the use of jquery function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.classname').not(this).not(':disabled').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

> So This is the condition that help you to ignor disable checkbox and that checkbox should not be selected or checked

Thank you @satpal

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
return !this.disabled && this.checked;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```